# Clear all cookie in Python request

Tags: python, cookies, request

I use Request python to post a form .
I need to clear all cookie before I post the form with request.
Do you have a solution ?

My python code :

```
url = "http://www.do-ain.com/ak/post"
session = requests.session()
r = session.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
r.headers.get('location')
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
payload = {'check': '0'}
cookies = {'fretx':'6544555X'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload,cookies=cookies)
```

Answer (score 4):

**CookieJar.clear([domain[, path[, name]]])**

If invoked without arguments, clear all cookies. If given a single argument, only cookies belonging to that domain will be removed. If given two arguments, cookies belonging to the specified domain and URL path are removed. If given three arguments, then the cookie with the specified domain, path and name is removed.